# How to use Sql Server Service Broker with Java

Tags: java, sql-server, service-broker

I am writting my application in java and sql server. There are some libraries I need that are only available in java. So I am forced to use Java as my programming language. After some research I am unable to find official resources for java and sql server service broker. Is there a way to use java and work with sql server service broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. You can issue a `receive` statement from the queue to get messages and do with them what you will from there. You don't need to do anything special just because it's Java.